# How to change the domain name in access URL of a web application hosted on MS Azure?

Tags: mongodb, azure, apache, grails, azure-web-app-service

I have a question about changing the domain name in access URL of a web application hosted on MS Azure. We have managed to recently create a clone of an existing Virtual Machine (VM) for a different project and the access URL for the clone is as shown below (Current URL) and this VM/instance is still private. We want to rename this to a different one as shown below (Expected URL). The web application is developed using below components and legacy source code link is available here [Click Here](https://github.com/BenaroyaResearch/gxbrowser). I would like to know how to change this URL domain name. Please assist me with this as I am still still learning and getting familiarized with this.

```
Apache Tomcat 6.0.24
Java 1.7.0_03
Apache http server 2.2
R 2.15.1 (R 3.1 suggested)
Mysql 5.1.41 (MySQL 5.5 suggested)
Mongo 2.02 (Mongo 2.4 suggested)
Grails 2.1.0
```

**Current URL**

[image]

**Expected URL**

[image]

Thank you,

Toufiq

Comment: This is rather  a configuration- or network-question, for which there are dedicated stackexchange sites. Check [help/on-topic] for stackoverflow's focus on concrete programming issues. Also, just as the browser can't understand PNGs in the URL field, we prefer [text as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13447).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a new public ip to the new vm (or create a LB, it's up to you) and create a dns entry on "gxbsidra.org" domain called "infection" pointing to the new ip.

Configure the software accordingly (tomcat and httpd) and you're done.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions. I will get in touch with System Administrator on this. In addition, please confirm which (tomcat and httpd) files or components needs to be configured. This will be very helpful.